# Mysql innerjoin very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, nhibernate

I have an SQL query that takes over 4 hours to complete.

The query is as follows

```
UPDATE carepathaction a1 
       INNER JOIN carepathaction a2 
               ON a1.sourceoid = a2.oid 
       INNER JOIN carepathgroup g 
               ON g.sourceoid = a2.carepathgroupoid 
       INNER JOIN carepathphase f 
               ON f.oid = g.carepathphaseoid 
SET    a1.carepathgroupoid = g.oid 
WHERE  f.code = 'EDIT'
```

He has to update 65000 items. Is there some optimalization i can do in this query?
CarePathAction

```
CREATE TABLE `carepathaction` 
  ( 
     `oid`                                INT(11) NOT NULL, 
     `typeid`                             CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'X', 
     `sequencenumber`                     INT(11) NOT NULL, 
     `description`                        VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL, 
     `duration`                           INT(11) NOT NULL comment 'In minutes', 
     `deadline`                           INT(11) NOT NULL comment 
'# dagen in combinatie met deadlineType (sinds begin traject of sinds begin deze actie)' 
     , 
`deadlinetype`                       INT(11) NOT NULL comment 
'1) = deadline sinds zorgpad\n2) = deadline sinds start deze actie\n3) = deadline sinds zorgpadfase'
     , 
`repeatperweek`                      INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`numbertorepeat`                     INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`carepathoid`                        INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`usertaskoid`                        INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`templateattachment`                 VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
`partyrolecategoryoid`               INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`automatic`                          BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0', 
`carepathphaseoid`                   INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`parentoid`                          INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`documentoid`                        INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`epdtemplateoid`                     INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`producttypeoid`                     INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`evaluateby`                         INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`pathlock`                           BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0', 
`carepathgroupoid`                   INT(11) NOT NULL, 
`activitygroupoid`                   INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`title`                              VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
`carepathactionswitchtype`           INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`modulesdomaincode`                  VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
`startday`                           INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`sourceoid`                          INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`templatefilename`                   VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`istask`                             BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0', 
`typecontact`                        INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`carepathactionepdoid`               INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`carepathactiontreatmentplanoid`     INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`clientportalenabled`                BIT(1) DEFAULT NULL, 
`startafternumberofdaysepddatefield` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`startafterdateepdfieldoid`          INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`epdtemplatefieldoid`                INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`oid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk1_idx` (`carepathoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk2_idx` (`carepathphaseoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk3_idx` (`documentoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk4_idx` (`epdtemplateoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk5_idx` (`producttypeoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk6_idx` (`carepathgroupoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk6_idx1` (`activitygroupoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk7_idx` (`parentoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk8_idx` (`usertaskoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk10_idx` (`partyrolecategoryoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk11_idx` (`carepathactionepdoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk12_idx` (`carepathactiontreatmentplanoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk13_idx` (`startafterdateepdfieldoid`), 
     KEY `carepathactionfk14_idx` (`epdtemplatefieldoid`), 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk14` FOREIGN KEY (`epdtemplatefieldoid`) 
     REFERENCES `epdtemplatefield` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no 
     action, 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`carepathoid`) REFERENCES 
     `carepath` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action, 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk10` FOREIGN KEY (`partyrolecategoryoid`) 
     REFERENCES `partyrolecategory` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no 
     action, 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk11` FOREIGN KEY (`carepathactionepdoid`) 
     REFERENCES `carepathaction` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action 
     , 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk12` FOREIGN KEY ( 
     `carepathactiontreatmentplanoid`) REFERENCES `carepathaction` (`oid`) ON 
     DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action, 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk13` FOREIGN KEY (`startafterdateepdfieldoid`) 
     REFERENCES `carepathaction` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action 
     , 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk2` FOREIGN KEY (`carepathphaseoid`) REFERENCES 
     `carepathphase` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action, 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk3` FOREIGN KEY (`documentoid`) REFERENCES 
     `document` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action, 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk4` FOREIGN KEY (`epdtemplateoid`) REFERENCES 
     `epdtemplate` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action, 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk5` FOREIGN KEY (`producttypeoid`) REFERENCES 
     `producttype` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action, 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk6` FOREIGN KEY (`carepathgroupoid`) REFERENCES 
     `carepathgroup` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action, 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk7` FOREIGN KEY (`parentoid`) REFERENCES 
     `carepathaction` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action, 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathactionfk8` FOREIGN KEY (`usertaskoid`) REFERENCES 
     `tasktoschedule` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action 
  )
```

CarePathGroup

```
CREATE TABLE `carepathgroup` 
  ( 
     `oid`              INT(11) NOT NULL, 
     `sequencenumber`   INT(11) NOT NULL, 
     `title`            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
     `carepathoid`      INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `carepathphaseoid` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
     `sourceoid`        INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`oid`), 
     KEY `carepathgroupfk1_idx` (`carepathoid`), 
     KEY `carepathgroupfk2_idx` (`carepathphaseoid`), 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathgroupfk2` FOREIGN KEY (`carepathphaseoid`) REFERENCES 
     `carepathphase` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action 
  )
```

CarePathPhase

```
CREATE TABLE `carepathphase` 
  ( 
     `oid`               INT(11) NOT NULL, 
     `code`              VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
     `description`       VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
     `sequencenumber`    INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
     `carepathoid`       INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
     `carepathphasetype` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
     `sourceoid`         INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`oid`), 
     KEY `carepathphasefk1_idx` (`carepathoid`), 
     CONSTRAINT `carepathphasefk1` FOREIGN KEY (`carepathoid`) REFERENCES 
     `carepath` (`oid`) ON DELETE no action ON UPDATE no action 
  )
```

explain

```
1   SIMPLE  f   ALL PRIMARY             61925   Using where
1   SIMPLE  g   ref CarePathGroupFK2_idx    CarePathGroupFK2_idx    4   amis.f.Oid  1   
1   SIMPLE  a1  ALL                 166582  Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  a2  eq_ref  PRIMARY,CarePathActionFK6_idx   PRIMARY 4   amis.a1.SourceOid   1   Using where
```

Comment: Pls post the create table for all tables in the join, so we can see the indexes. Pls change the query into a select and post the results of the explain here as well.

Comment: I hope this is enough info? The Select has 65000 rows so i cant post them here

Comment: No, it's not enough. I explicitly asked for the create table statements to see the indexes. I did not ask for the results of the select to be disclosed, I asked you to run an explain on the select and post the results of the explain.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding i have included the asked items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ALL join types in the explain, these are the ones you need to focus (for details see [mysql documentation on explain output](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types)).

The create table statements show that:

1. You do not have index on the carepathphase.code field, which is used in the where criteria, so you should rectify that.
2. There is no index on carepathaction.sourceoid, which is used in the join, so you should create one there. You may try to create a combined index on oid, sourceoid fields (or the other way around) because mysql may be able to use the combined index to match the rows.

Run explain on the select (if you have mysql v5.6 or newer, then you can run it directly on the update) after adding the indexes and see, if the ALLs change. The 2nd all next to a2 seems to be the real critical stuff to me.